# "Passive" state machine - correct term?

Tags: model, uml, design-patterns, state-machine

I am looking for the correct term of a logical construct that I would call "**passive state machine**".

Imagine this embedded device: Some lower program layer handles a chip card reader and reacts on the user input by determining three states: "Card in", "Card out", "Card error". Adequate low-level actions are performed here. Call this a state machine.

The lower layer reports the state to some **upper program layer** which reacts on **changes** and communicates with the rest of the system, i.e. sends messages, switches LEDs etc.

The program logic in this *upper layer* can also be modelled (UML 2) like a simplified state machine on its own: it has transitions between the states and - most importantly - **entry and exit actions**. The states are basically the same as in the lower layer, but not necessary (e.g. might be reduced to "Card OK", "Card not OK").

The big difference is that this "upper layer state machine" doesn't do any **decision** - it merely **reacts** on the state it gets from the lower level and provides actions. The state/transition/action model is just a nice way to visualise the logic to the reader (and, of course, to tell the compiler what to do...) in a well-arranged way.

Or, put it differently: in a "real" state machine, as I understand it, the *state's* logic decides the next state to transition to. In the "passive" variant, some *outer* entity does the decision and the states follow accordingly. Consequence: *all* transistions between the states must be possible in the upper level.

But is this actually a "finite state *machine*" (I imagine something active here)? Or is there a better term around that ephasises the passive character of this model?

Edit: Thanks for the replies! Two figures to clarify. Of course both are state machines. However I see some qualitative difference: imagine the "lower level" SM has direct contact to the hardware (valves, sensors) and knows the system it reflects. For instance, only state "normal" can react to the "test button", the others can't. Not all transitions are possible.
The "higher level" is considered "dumb" and should only visualise/report the input it gets from lower level. So *all* transitions must be possible. The state-switch-logic is the same for all states an would be implemented *outside* the states (thinking as a programmer) to avoid redundancy. It doesn't decide, it just does the entry/exit actions.

Lower level:
[image]

Higher level:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you just have a hierarchical state machine (which state charts, and so UML do support).  Perhaps if you could post a diagram of your state machine we could provide a better opinion, but it sounds as if your "lower level" machine would be modeled as a (composite) state in the "upper layer".  And you have transitions from that state to other states or perhaps just back to itself?

All FSMs are in some sense "passive".  They define the set of valid states, the allowable transitions between them and the triggers (conditions) that cause the transitions to occur and the (optional) actions that occur during the transition.  Does your upper level state machine not follow this model?

Comment: Thanks Eoin, too. See my edit in the question and comment to vainolo.

Comment: Now I see both state machines, I've actually got a few doubts that the top one is really a state machine.  It doesn't have any events on the transitions, so the transitions will never happen.  The machine will just sit in "Normal" state.  The way that the hierarchical state machines formalism works is that a state in a state machine can be decomposed into a lower level state machine.  In your case, I don't think that's what's happening is it?  The structure of the upper state machine mirrors the lower one.  But I don't see how events get passed between them.  Sorry if I'm missing something.

Comment: The transistions are switched from outside: imagine some piece of code which reads the lower SM and "triggers" the "upper" transition. That's what I mean with "passive". --- I see the "upper" one as the place to put the appropriate actions to, for the sake of a clear graphical presentation with UML. I really like the idea of "entry/exit" actions. You can also model the "upper" as a table or with if-statements: "if lower level enters normal state, switch LEDs off; else if lower level enters 'valve A defect', turn red LED on; if it exits this state, turn red LED off;" etc.

Comment: Yes, I think I understand now.  You have two parallel state machines in different system components linked so that events propagate from the one to the other?  In which case, I don't think you can show that link directly in UML state charts (as I mentioned above, the hierarchy in the state charts formalism nests sub-state charts within states of the higher level one).  I think you need to do two things: (a) add the events that cause the transitions to happen to the upper state machine; (b) create a component model to show the structure that propagates events between the machines.

Answer (score 1):

From your previous to last sentence, I think you have misunderstood state machines. A state machine does not decide on the transitions, but takes them when it receives an `event`/`trigger` that enables the transition. A basic state machine is actually passive. If a state has no `completion` transitions, the machine waits until it receives a trigger that can move it to a connected state.

Comment: thanks vainolo. I understand that both are state machines. See my edit. With "decide" I mean: the code to test for a distinct trigger condition might only be executed in a certain state. In other states, the condition is not tested (in my example, only "normal" tests the "button"). In contrast, in the "higher level" SM, no such test is done _in_ a state. The trigger is the same for all states: "oh, state has changed".
I was wondering if there is a term to express this semantic difference.

Comment: I don't understand why you need the two machines. Why not add the entry/exit/etc to the "Lower level" state machine? what do you gain from having these two machines, except for more complexity?

Comment: Because I devide resposibilities: the actual project has a chip card wrapper class which does some basic validity tests (magic ID, checksum etc.) and delivers ready evaluated states ("Card in", "Card out", "Card error") to the main workflow (high level). User interaction, messaging and processing the card content are done there. Upper levels should not know _how_ to check a card validity but lower levels do. Tomorrow we might use a complete different card type and the state action might be different at lower level. Yet the interface to the upper level (and the three states) will be the same.